# Multiple DTOs for same service

Tags: spring, rest

Let's say I have two clients who want to use my service via `REST`, but each one wants to end their own `JSON` format in the request body. One proposed solution was to create two different DTOs to match each format and the two corresponding REST endpoints to expect them, e.g.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/my/service/v1")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> myServiceV1(
        @RequestBody ClientDto1 dto) { ...}

@PostMapping(value = "/my/service/v2")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> myServiceV2(
            @RequestBody ClientDto2 dto) { ...}
```

I don't like this idea for several reasons, am I right to assume that this is bad practice? Most importantly, what alternatives do I have?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use the same DTO, marking required false? In this case, some validation needs to be in place and this also doesn't seem to very much clean, putting two things in a single place and finally, maintainability is a big challenge. Your way seems to be clean at least changes to one doesn't impact the other.

Comment: @NirajJha thanks for replying. It is not my way, quite the contrary I hate the exposed proposal. Maintainability is terrible and we also have duplication of efforts.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted samples of the request. But if we assume there are lots of similarities between request1 and request2, you could create a dto containg all of the fields from both and annotating it with Jackson's

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Dto {}
```

Which will prevent null parameters from showing in your response, thus, you won't have to create separate dto for every request.